# Replace Win32_Product class in GPO WMI filter

Tags: wmi, gpo

I actually use a WMI filter in multiple GPO with call at Win32_Product class. Example: Select * from Win32_Product WHERE ( Caption="Microsoft Office Standard 2016")
Unfortunately it is not a good practise : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/windows-installer-reconfigured-all-applications
I don't have SSCM client to directly use Win32reg_AddRemovePrograms class.

Is there an other simple way to filter the application of the GPO (Like in the example on only computer with Microsoft Office Standard 2016). Create a WMI filter on GPO to check specific registred keys for example instead of Caption attribute ?

Regards

Albert

Use Win32reg_AddRemovePrograms -> SSCM client not installed
Use StdRegProv -> No result maybe because wrong namespaces

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`SELECT Status FROM Win32_Directory WHERE Name = 'Path_to_your_Office_installation'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).